# Eagerly load result of a belongsToMany association in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently building a database layout with Sequelize as my ORM. I have a model layout that consists of a User, and an App model.
A User can belong to many Apps (i.e. having access to them) through the AppUsers table.
An App belongs to a User.

I have implemented this in the App model like this

```js
classMethods: {
  associate: function (models) {
    App.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      constraints: false,
      as: 'owner'
    });

    App.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: {
        model: models.AppUser,
        unique: true
      },
      foreignKey: 'app_id',
      otherKey: 'user_id',
      constraints: false
    });
  }
}
```

and in the User model like this

```js
classMethods: {
  associate: function (models) {
    User.belongsToMany(models.App, {
      through: {
        model: models.AppUser,
        unique: true
      },
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      otherKey: 'app_id',
      constraints: false,
      as: 'apps'
    });

    User.hasMany(models.App, {
      foreignKey: 'owner_id',
      constraints: false,
      scope: {
        owner_type: 'user'
      },
      as: 'ownApps'
    });
  }
}
```

Now to my actual question:
I'm looking for a way to query the apps a user has access to (i.e. `user.getApps()`) and have the owner information eagerly loaded and already included in the response to that query.

I have played with `include:` and `scope:` in the `User.belongsToMany(models.App, …` association but none of them yielded the desired result.
Is there a way to do this or do I need to write a custom `App.findAll()` query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the answer is fairly easy:
Simply adding the `include` to the associated model function did the trick:

```js
user.getApps({ include: [{ model: models.User, as: 'owner' }] })
```